# Admob on all Activities?

Tags: android, admob

I have got one question. Can I make adversities Admob on all my Activities in one Application? I know how to do it, but i don't know it is good with Google License?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put advertisements in all of your activities.

Make sure you are following all of the [Guidelines](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en#number) though.